# AngularJS: prepend "http://" to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input for url. I would like to automatically prepend "http://" to the user value, if it does not already exist. I would like to avoid using $watch because there are about 30 such inputs in a single controller...

How should I approach this?

Comment: Do you want to apply it when the input-form is being submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say with a classic regex on the blur event you should be fine:

```
<div ng-blur="check(thismodel)"></div>
```

#

```
$scope.check = function($url){
  if (!/^(?:(ftp|http|https)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){2,6}$/gi.test($url)) {
      $url = "http://" + $url;
  }
}
```